# Heroku Apache, Parse HTML also as PHP

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, heroku

How can I modify .htaccess and httpd.conf in Heroku? I connected it with a repository on Github.

In Github I've tried multiple things, those all don't work. Putting httpd.conf in a folder called /conf/httpd/default.conf didn't work, not sure not even in the repo root it worked, when I tried to put httpd.conf and .htaccess in there, nothing ever happens and I'm not sure why.

I am using the apache2 buildpack from Heroku that is inside a Procfile heroku-php-apache2

I am trying to tell the httpd.conf to parse .html also with php, so I can include things in it.

There is that thing on Github https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php not sure if that can help.

**Update:**

Apperantly when using -c httpd.conf to tell where the httpd.conf is, it started recognising it and using it, what I get now is this:

`no listening sockets available, shutting down`

**Update:**

I used -C httpd.conf and it included it now, the problem is
The changes I want to make do not really apply. I'm trying to parse HTML also as PHP.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want the http server to interpret files marked as html as if they were php files? Why don't you simply rename the files?

Comment: I want to include html inside html by using php. As example navigation.php that has echo and html in it, because if I don't do that. I need to create a website only using php and echo which doesn't look good.

Comment: No idea what you mean by all that. _Maybe_ you have the impression that a URL ending in a file name that has a ".html" ending somehow "looks good"? Please do a bit of research, what is displayed in a URL is _completely_ independent from how the content is generated and how it is identified, _if you want to_ .

Comment: In short, make <?php ?> work inside html files

Comment: We all understood that much. You can easily do that by changing the URL such that it ends in ".php". And if that, for some reason, is "ugly" to you, then leave the ending ".html" (why an ending at all?) and internally rewrite the requests to a physical file named with a ".php" ending.

Comment: but then I can't use html????
I'm not looking with what it ends with if it's .php or .html

If I use .php I can use <?php ?> but I can't use html

Comment: You apparently have not understood the origins of php. A php file traditionally is nothing but an html file. You do not need any `echo` statement for that. Please, again, do some research.

Comment: I can try to run an html tag inside php again, last time I did that it didn't do changes, be it locally or on a server

Comment: okay, I recall it wrong, my fault

Comment: What I tried to do was to parse php inside html, because of the look and especially the formatting within editor files and some other reasons when switching through different devices
but if it ends with .html doesn't really matter since I plan to remove the .extension after everything

Comment: Maybe this will shed some light, an example: `<html><body><h1>My title</h1></body></html>` is a perfectly fine php file. Just as `<html><body><h1><?php echo "My title" ?></h1></body></html>` is...

Comment: yep but I can use php only on a server and let's say I have to test something but can't access a server, that's one of the other reasons

Comment: I've heard people call it also .phtml but yeah I mean the server is the problem

Comment: I have the impression you also have a wrong concept of what the term "server" actually refers to. A "server" is _not_ a system or machine, but a software. A software that serves content, for example html. Without such a software you are not able to "include" something. What should do the inclusion in the absence of a server software? Any computer can be a server, actually several servers at once and as a matter of fact all of today's systems _are_ servers. You can simply install a server software on whatever system you are working on.

Comment: I just want to not copypaste everything in an html file, such as navigator or use wordpress because features of wordpress are disabled because it's the standard version

Comment: You are looking for excuses apparently. "wordpress" has _nothing_ to do with all this. You want to serve html content and use an inclusion feature. Easiest is to use php for that, that is _exactly_ what php is for, originally. So why don't you simply use it? I mean it is your decision, but don't try to find issues where there are none, that is all I am saying.

Comment: .php doesn't run on stuff that isn't from a server, that has php installed on such as XAMPP. And if I can't install xampp I would have troubles, but I think I have no other choice, unless I don't do it on heroku, but yeah.

Comment: Again: you have a miss conception of what a server actually is. Even though installing a distribution as XAMPP is easy enough (actually it is even easier to simply install its compoments with a few mouse clicks), you even have multiple other choices: nginx, lightty, ... Or simply use the php builtin http server. You won't get around using _something_ that is able to include something. HTML cannot include something, it is a passive format. You yourself wrote that you want to use php for the inclusion. Fine. So do it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up using PHP.

You could try it with a custom buildpack but I don't know how to make one so it can actually use it's own httpd.conf and not the one from the heroku php buildpack.